# Multirow vertical aligment issue

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow

I am having issues with creating my table with multirow. Vertical aligment is not centered properly (letters are more at "top"). I think that is caused by "hline". When I use "toprule, midrule,.." aligment is good, but these commands have has issues with broken vertical borders. Please help me.

`\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbf]
  \center
  \begin{tabular}{|M{1.7cm}|M{1.8cm}|}
    \hline
   bla &bla\\
\hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{bla}
&bla\\   \cline{2-2}
&bla\\  \cline{2-2}
&bla\\  \cline{2-2}
&bla\\  \cline{2-2}
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
\end{document}`

[image]

Comment: It looks optically not centered because none of your content has "descenders" (letters that protrude below the baseline). Try with "jab" or "tag" instead of "bla" and you will see.

Comment: Content of `multirow` cell is well centered. If you not satisfied with it, `multirow` macro offer option for manual adjustment of cell content position: `\multirow{nrows}[bigstruts]{width}[fixup]{text}` where in `fixup` you write lenght for offset content (positive to move up, negative to move down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\extrarowheight` or, better, don't use vertical lines and load booktabs. Here is a demo of both solutions:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes[t]{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering%
  \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
  \begin{tabular}{|M{1.7cm}|M{1.8cm}|}
    \hline
    bla & bla \\
    \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{bla} & bla \\
    \cline{2-2} & bla \\
    \cline{2-2} & bla \\
    \cline{2-2} & bla \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering%
  \begin{tabular}{M{1.7cm} M{1.8cm}}
    \toprule
    bla & bla \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}{*}{bla} & bla \\[2pt]
                         & bla \\[2pt]
                         & bla \\[2pt]
                         & bla \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]