# Table size & vertical align

Tags: multirow, size, vertical

I want to make my table bigger and make all entries in table align vertically.

This is my code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{My Table}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} \\\cline{2-5}
          & type1 & type2 & type1 & type2 \\\hline
        a & xx    & xx    & xx    & xx    \\\hline
        b & xx    & xx    & xx    & xx    \\\hline
        c & xx    & xx    & xx    & xx    \\\hline      
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by making a table "bigger". E.g., should the font size be increased? Or, should the entries be spread out more horizontally and/or vertically?

Comment: If you just put the expression \large after [h], like \begin{table}[h]\large, does that make it bigger in the way that you want?

Comment: Is your problem answered by https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279274/multirow-vertical-aligment-issue?rq=1

Comment: @Mico I think I can handle size of table using \large !! Thanks you !!

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay I really thank to you!! and, I tried to find lots of solution in here, TeX.SE., but I can't apply those solutions here to mine, because, as soon as I used code like {|P{1cm}|P{1cm}|P{1cm}|P{1cm}|P{1cm}|}, I get some error message, illegal pream-token (P): 'c' used.

Comment: Is there any solution to detach entries from upper line of each cell here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest solution is to use booktabs instead of having vertical and horizontal lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]\large
\caption{My Table}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} \\
          & type1 & type2 & type1 & type2 \\ \midrule
        a & xx    & xx    & xx    & xx    \\
        b & xx    & xx    & xx    & xx    \\
        c & xx    & xx    & xx    & xx    \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: image of table]